# Sending MIDI Signals to a pc with Raspberry PI - Scrypt is running slow

Tags: python, performance, loops, raspberry-pi

a lot of the times when I run this code its running slowly.

Im sending simple midi signals to the pc by using a Raspberry PI Zero W.
I want to be able to control a knob in a software called ableton(DAW).

I use a analog to digital converter (hardware) on the breadboard.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- Simple example of reading the MCP3008 analog 
# input channels and printing them all out. Author: Tony DiCola License: 
# Public Domain
import time
import os
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_MCP3008

SPI_PORT = 0
SPI_DEVICE = 0
mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE))
os.chdir("/home/pi/SendMIDI/")
  while True:
pot0 = str(mcp.read_adc(0) * 16)
time.sleep(0.0001)
#if pot0c != pot0:
os.system("./sendmidi dev f_midi pb " + pot0)
```

So i want to read the MCP3008 A/D Converter and pass it trough the file 'sendmidi'.

Here's the slow running code:
https://i.gyazo.com/e1a9d70cf433668794a2fb98394c7973.mp4

here's the fast running code:
https://i.gyazo.com/2599f4e6ca9b146b55d468330c937a64.mp4

I think it has something to do with the infinite loop not properly executing or using a lot of resource. Can you guys help to make it run smooth every time?

Comment: Why have you got an infinite loop doing nothing? `while True:`

Comment: @MarkSetchell because it needs to constantly check if i have moved a physical device called potentiometer attached to the raspberry. So basically i use it as a event handler

Comment: Does anybody know?